# How to download all repo's markdown pages on GitHub and convert them to reStructuredText?

Tags: github, restructuredtext, github-api, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

My repository has a lot of wiki pages written Markdown.
I want to convert them all to reStructuredText so they can be compiled into a separate Sphinx documentation project.

Answer (score 0):

http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

`pandoc` can convert Markdown to reStructuredText, so try that.